# What are the clear bubbles for?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I know that the yellow circles that drop from enemies are money, and the green ones are HP, but I have noticed that sometimes transparent bubbles drop from enemies. What are these for?

(I haven't played the game in about 4 months, so if it was explained, I have totally forgotten.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: MP Orb]

If you're talking about this kind of bubble, it's an [MP Orb](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/MP_Recovery). As the name suggests, it restores your MP.

Photo used from http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's why I never notice anything changing - I rarely use MP, so it is usually full.

Comment: The orb in that picture looks like it might actually be one of the orbs at Hallow Bastion. But the meat of the answer is correct, they are MP orbs.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was hallow bastion too. I haven't played this game in ages so I found a picture on the Internet.